# TortoiseSVN 1.9.4 revert option missing

Tags: svn, tortoisesvn, revert

I am trying to revert a change to a file in TortoiseSVN 1.9.4.  I have followed the documentation [here](https://tortoisesvn.net/docs/release/TortoiseSVN_en/tsvn-howto-rollback.html) but there is no *Revert* option in the Context Menu for the file.

This is what I'm getting for the Context Menu for the specific revision I would like to revert to:

[image: My context menu.]

All similar questions I've found here on Stack Overflow have had solutions similar to what is in the documentation. I suspect that I may have a bad install, but would like to confirm.

It is also totally possible that I'm completely misunderstanding the documentation, and, without adequate screenshots to guide me, I may just need someone smarter than I to point me in the right direction.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You've launched the log dialogue from the "Repo-browser" dialogue so there's no linked working copy to revert changes to. I suggest you try again from a working copy's "Show log" dialogue:

[image: Working copy log messages]

Comment: Ahh, this works.  Really wish the documentation made that more apparent.  Thank you.